# Ambiguty and no suitable method found error in java overloading

Tags: java

Suppose I have one overloaded class like below

```
class Test{
    public void m1(int a,float b){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
    public void m1(float a,int b){
        System.out.println("hai"); 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test t = new Test();
        t.m1(10,10);//error
        t.m1(10.5f,10.6f);//error
    }
}
```

when I call `m1()` method with two int values like `m1(10,10)` the error is

```
 error: reference to m1 is ambiguous, both method m1(int,float) in Test and method m1(float,int) in Test match
t.m1(10,10);
 ^
```

and when I call `m1()` method with two float values like `m1(10.5f,10.6f)` error is

```
error: no suitable method found for m1(float,float)
t.m1(10.5f,10.6f);
 ^
method Test.m1(float,int) is not applicable
  (actual argument float cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)
method Test.m1(int,float) is not applicable
  (actual argument float cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion)
```

Can anyone please explain the reason, why this program shows two different types of errors?

Comment: I wonder why you expect equals errors? How should the compiler _promote_ `float` to an `int`, when `int` is the "lower" datatype which causes data loss?

Comment: I thought in method area compiler didn't found the methods which I am calling so I expected `no suitable method error` for both method calls

Comment: And why do you think that both methods aren't suitable, when you call them with `int`?

Answer (score 5):

When you are trying to pass an `int` argument to a method that expects a `float`, the argument can be automatically converted from `int` to `float` via [widening primitive conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) (a widening primitive conversion does not lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value). Therefore both your methods can execute the call `t.m1(10,10)`, and the compiler can't choose between the two (since both require a conversion of one of the arguments from `int` to `float`, so none of the two methods is more appropriate than the other for the given arguments). Hence the `reference to m1 is ambiguous` error.

When you are passing a `float` argument to a method that expects an `int`, the argument can't be converted to `int` without an explicit cast to `int`, since there would be a loss of precision when the `float` is truncated to `int`. Therefore none of your methods can execute `t.m1(10.5f,10.6f)`.

Comment: "converted from int to float without loss of data" Generally (for all ints) this is not correct.

Comment: @Matthias You are right. I was inaccurate. I'll edit.